# How to get periodId on DashMetrics

Tags: javascript, dash.js

In dash.js there is a function getBandwidthForRepresentation() on file DashMetrics.js. It needs two parameters: representationId and periodId. I can use getCurrentRepresentationSwitch() to get representationId. But i don't know how to get periodId? With which function can i get the data?

I tried to see example on dash-reference-client, it is confusing and still have no idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know your question is kind of old and you are probably not needing this anymore, but I'll send some code in case someone needs it eventually.

As you stated, `getBandwidthForRepresentation()` expects 2 parameters: `representationId` and `periodId`

How to get **representationId**:

- you need to get metrics: `var metrics = player.getMetricsFor('video')`
- and dashMetrics: `var dashMetrics = player.getDashMetrics()`
- now we get representationId: `var representationId = dashMetrics.getCurrentRepresentationSwitch(metrics).to`

How to get **peropdId**:

- we get the active stream info: `var streamInfo = player.getActiveStream().getStreamInfo()`
- we use index as periodId: `var periodId = streamInfo.index`

How to get **bandwidth**:

- we can now get bandwidth: `var bandwidth = dashMetrics.getBandwidthForRepresentation(representationId, periodId)`

Full Code:

```
var metrics = player.getMetricsFor('video')
var dashMetrics = player.getDashMetrics()
var representationId = dashMetrics.getCurrentRepresentationSwitch(metrics).to
var streamInfo = player.getActiveStream().getStreamInfo()
var periodId = streamInfo.index
var bandwidth = dashMetrics.getBandwidthForRepresentation(representationId, periodId)
```

Hope it helps